# RegEnumValue crashes application

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I am currently learning how to work with the registry using c++. I have made an application that is supposed to see if a certain value in a certain key exists. However, the application crashes as soon as it reaches RegEnumValue(). Any ideas to what the problem might be?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>

using namespace std;

bool registerKeyExists(char* key, char* subkey);

int main()
{
    while(true){
        if(registerKeyExists("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "SynTPEnh")){
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

bool registerKeyExists(char* key, char* subkey){
    HKEY keyEnum;
    if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key, 0, KEY_READ, &keyEnum) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
        char* valueName;
        DWORD valueSize = 100;
        DWORD cbName;
        FILETIME lastFiletime;
        DWORD i = 0;
        DWORD returnCode = ERROR_SUCCESS;
        while(returnCode == ERROR_SUCCESS){
            cout << "This show!" << endl;
            returnCode = RegEnumValue(keyEnum, i, valueName, &valueSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            cout << "This doesn't show!" << endl;
            if(valueName == subkey)
                return true;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not provided any space for the name of the value. You are passing an uninitialised pointer `valueName` to `RegEnumValue()`, which it rejects (apparently, by way of crashing your app). Try the following instead:

```
char valueName[100];
DWORD valueSize = sizeof(valueName);
```

This reserves 100 characters for the returned value name.

You will also want to use `strcmp()` instead of `==` for testing string values:

```
if (strcmp(valueName, subkey) == 0) ...
```

Comment: Don't forget to compare the sizes as well! `strlen(valueName) == strlen(subkey)`

Comment: @KlemensBaum: There is no need to compare the sizes when using `strcmp()`. If the lengths are different, `strcmp()` will not return 0.

Answer (score 3):

From the SDK documention for RegEnumValue():

```
LONG WINAPI RegEnumValue(
  __in         HKEY hKey,
  __in         DWORD dwIndex,
  __out        LPTSTR lpValueName,         // <=== here
  __inout      LPDWORD lpcchValueName,
  __reserved   LPDWORD lpReserved,
  __out_opt    LPDWORD lpType,
  __out_opt    LPBYTE lpData,
  __inout_opt  LPDWORD lpcbData
);
```

Notice the `__out` SAL annotation on the lpValueName argument.  That means "were are going to *write* through the pointer you supplied".  And in particular, write the name of the value as documented in the rest of the SDK article.

Problem is, you didn't pass an initialized pointer that points to memory that can be written.  A TCHAR[] array big enough to receive the string, as indicated by the next argument, lpcchValueName.   You left it uninitialized.  And fibbed by saying you allocated 100 characters for the array.

Kaboom.